# polynomial vector space inner product function and Gram-Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an inner product

$\langle p,q \rangle = p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$ in $P_2(R)$

and standard basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$

I'm using Gram-Schmidt to compute orthogonal vectors but I'm unclear in this case how the vector parameter is being substituted in the inner product equation.

For example according to a worked solution:

$\langle 1,1 \rangle  = (1)(1) + (1)(1) + (1)(1) = 3$

$\langle x,1 \rangle  = (0)(1) + (1)(1) + (2)(1) = 3$

$\langle x^2,1 \rangle  = (0)(1) + (1)(1) + (4)(1) = 5$

and further

$\langle x^2,x-1 \rangle   = (0)(-1) + (1)(0) + (4)(1) = 4$

$\langle x-1,x-1\rangle   = (-1)(-1) + (0)(0) + (1)(1) = 2$

How are the values inside the brackets derived?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are evaluating the polynomials in the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$ for $x=0, 1, 2$.

Consider the first inner product $\langle1, 1 \rangle$. Here $p$ and $q$ are the polynomials that output $1$ for every input. Namely, $p(x)=1$ and $q(x)=1$ for all $x$.  So, according to the given formula $$\langle p, q\rangle = p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)$$

We see that $$\langle 1, 1\rangle=p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)p(2)q(2)=(1)(1)+(1)(1)+(1)(1)=3$$

Similarly, for the second inner product $\langle x, 1\rangle$, the polynomial $p(x)=x$ and $q(x)=1$ for all $x$. Using the given formula we see that $$\langle x, 1\rangle =p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)=(0)(1)+(1)(1)+(2)(1)=3$$

As you might have guesses, in the third inner product $\langle x^2, 1\rangle$, the polynomial $p(x)=x^2$ and $q(x)=1$. Using the given formula we see that $$\langle x^2, 1\rangle =p(0)q(0)+p(1)q(1)+p(2)q(2)=(0)(1)+(1)(1)+(4)(1)=5$$

Comment: Thank you but Im still not making the connection - I thought P(0) meant output terms of degree 0 (constants), P(1) terms of degree 1, eg $x$ etc. How does P(0) = P(1) = P(2) = 1 when p = 1? (Im not suggesting you're incorrect - I just don't understand it)

Comment: @haz That is the definition of the polynomial. The polynomial $p(x)=1$ outputs the number $1$ for every value of $x$. So, $p(0)=1, p(2)=1, p(\pi)=1, p(e)=1$. The polynomial always return the number $1$ no matter what the input is.

Comment: Why does $x^2$ return $p(0) = 0$, $p(1) =1$ and $p(2) = 4$ ?

Comment: @haz Because $0^2=0, 1^2=1$ and $2^2=4$. This is the polynomial that squares a number. Namely, the polynomial $p(x)=x^2$ squares any number that is given to it. So, $p(2)=2^2=4, p(3)=3^2=9, p(\sqrt 2)=(\sqrt 2)^2=2$.

Comment: good grief - thank you - that's what you get when doing homework with covid :)

Comment: @haz Glad I could help!